# The option for the SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform is not available in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

One of our users reported an issue in a specific SharePoint Online classic Team site. On this site, SharePoint Designer 2013 does not allow us to create Workflows 2013. I checked and confirm that I also can't create 2013 Workflows.

**Does anyone know how is this possible allow/disallow or enable/disable workflow 2013 engine for a specific site?**

[image]

**Message from SharePoint Designer**

> The option for the SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform is not available
> because the workflow service is not configured on the server. Please
> contact your server administrator.

**Addition info**

- All other sites allow us to create 2013 workflows with no issues.
- I am a site collection administrator.
- Custom scripts are allowed at the site.

**Tenant settings**
[image]

**Update - found a solution**

I have also activated the Workflow feature under the **Workflow settings** > **Workflow Health**

[image]

[image]

Result: <s>Still no Workflow 2013 option listed.</s> It worked after a 10-min delay.

Comment: Are 2013 WFs enabled in the SPO Admin center?

Comment: Yes, included the screenshot

Comment: Make sure the client is up to date, at least SP Designer 2013 + SP1. With all that being said, I'd strongly suggest not creating new 2013 WFs. I'm just waiting for MSFT to announce a sunset date like they did for 2010 WFs. Speculation of course, but it's ancient tech :)

Comment: Yes, we strongly encourage users to not create new workflows. But Power Automate will take a few months to roll out at that particular tenant. And In the meanwhile some site owners are desperate to introduce some automation. Without any alternatives they choose what is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2013 Workflow feature just showed up after some time. This is what worked:
I have activated the Workflow feature under the **Workflow settings** > **Workflow Health**

[image]

[image]

**Result**

[image]